# Split model into cube over a perfectly aligned grid

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool, boolean-modifier

I am interested in taking a model and splitting it into 1x1x1 cubes.

For the sake of a simple example, in my attempt, I have a simple model, the default cube in blender scaled up by 2. I have formed a grid from another 1x1x1 cube using array modifiers, so that I can split the initial cube by this grid. I want to break down my initial model into 1x1x1 parts. So, I applied a Boolean modifier with Intersect over the grid cube.

[image]

It might be hard to see but I did get close to this result:

[image]

However, I had to set the array modifier offset to 1.001. In case it is a 1, I get a blank result, the intersection seems to return no results.

[image]

My question is why is this 1.001 necessary, and is it creating an uneven split? In my use case it is extremely important that the split is a perfectly even split, a very small offset is not acceptable. Is there a better approach?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it's just cubes, one would just make the cubes separately and snap them to each other. What is the actual situation and context?

Comment: Are you looking for voxels https://youtu.be/ZFKUaXvieBQ

Comment: The 1.001 is necessary because if the array instances are directly face on face, the _Boolean_ modifier does not "see" two faces by which to divide the larger cube. If two array faces are in the exact same location, they will get treated as one cutting plane by the _Boolean_ modifier. So with a distance of 1.000 the faces of the larger cube will be subdivided (as you can see e.g. in _Wireframe_ mode), but not split with faces created on the inside... and therefore the subdividing edges are not visible in _Solid_ mode like on other subdivided meshes without an angle between adjacent faces.